# can not delete the entity which have collection as child with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping

NOTE:

This is a croass post at:[hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1010241&p=2443214#p2443214)

Since I got no answer ,so I ask here to see if I can get some help. :)

If this is solved here,I will post the answer in the hibernate forum. :)

---

In my application,I have some entities which own some collections,when I have no idea to delete them.

This is the core codes of my eneity:

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(
      name = "t_task")
public class Task {
   private int            id;
   private List<TaskStep>   steps   = new ArrayList<TaskStep>();

   public Task() {
      this.createTime = new Date();
   }
   public Task(String name) {
      this();
      this.name = name;
   }
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   @OneToMany(
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(
         name = "task_id",
         nullable = false)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @IndexColumn(
         name = "position")
   public List<TaskStep> getSteps() {
      return steps;
   }
   // domain method
   public void addSteps(TaskStep ts) {
      steps.add(ts);
      ts.setTask(this);
   }

   public void removeStep(TaskStep ts) {
      steps.remove(ts);
   }

   // setter
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public void setSteps(List<TaskStep> steps) {
      this.steps = steps;
      for (TaskStep st : steps) {
         st.setTask(this);
      }
   }

}


//TaskStep:

@Entity
@Table(
      name = "t_taskstep")
public class TaskStep {
   private int            id;
   private List<Operator>   operator   = new ArrayList<Operator>();
   private Task         task;

   public TaskStep() {}

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   @ManyToMany(
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   public List<Operator> getOperator() {
      return operator;
   }

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(
         name = "task_id",
         nullable = false,
         updatable = false,
         insertable = false)
   public Task getTask() {
      return task;
   }
   // domain method start
   public void addOperator(Operator op) {
      operator.add(op);
   }
   // setter
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public void setOperator(List<Operator> operator) {
      this.operator = operator;
   }

   public void setTask(Task task) {
      this.task = task;
   }
}

//Operator:
@Entity
@Table(
      name = "t_operator")
public class Operator {
   private int            id;
   private List<TaskStep>   steps   = new ArrayList<TaskStep>();

   public Operator() {}
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   // //setter
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public void setSteps(List<TaskStep> steps) {
      this.steps = steps;
   }
   @ManyToMany(
         mappedBy = "operator")
   public List<TaskStep> getSteps() {
      return steps;
   }
}
```

In the db,there are tables of "t_task","t_operator","t_step","t_step_operator".

I use this manner to remove the task:
Code:
taskDao.delTaskById(5);

This is the dao:

Code:

```
   public void delTaskById(int id) {
      Task t = queryTaskById(id);
      Session sess = factory.getCurrentSession();
      try {
         sess.beginTransaction();
         sess.delete(t); // 1)
         sess.flush();
         sess.getTransaction().commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         sess.getTransaction().rollback();
      }
   }
```

I got a error which said "can not delete or update a parent row....".

Then I tried use the repalce the

```
sess.delete(t)
```

to

```
sess.createQuery("delete from Task t where t.id="+id).executeUpdate()
```

I got now error,but the task is not removed actually.

I have set the cascade in the mapping. for example,for the taskstesps in the task object,I set cascade.type=all,so I think when hibernate try to delete the task,it should del its realted tasksteps as well,and when it try to delete a taskstep object, it will find that the "t_step_t_operator" table is referring the id in "t_step",so I also set "cascade=all" for the "step" field in task class.
But seems that what is going on is not what I thought....

What is the problem? I am going to crazy!

Any one can do me a favor?

BWT,what does the cascade meaning?

For example:
 In the TaskStep calss,I have a List of Operators;

```
   //Class:TaskStep.
   @ManyToMany(
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   public List<Operator> getOperator() {
      return operator;
   }
```

In the above exmaple,I set cascade = all,does this mean no matter what operation(curd) to the TaskStep,it will do the same operation to the Opeartors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want (to simulate) a bidirectional relation without a join table, you must do this by creating two unidirectional relations and inform Hibernate about the relation between them - by using mappedBy, as JB Nizet says, but also keeping the other (@ManyToOne) mapping

@JoinColumn can be used e.g if you want to only map the @OneToMay side of a relation but still don't want a join table - you'll point out a column in other table that should be used, normally unidirectional references don't affect the referenced table and instead uses join tables. You prob don't need @JoinColumn in this case, since by default PK (id) is used in FK constraints in bidirectional relations (t_taskstep.task_id column will have FK constraint to t_task.id)

Cascade attribute will cause Create/Delete actions (updates are implicitly handled by EntityManager/Session) on owning entities to cascade down to (in your case) all entities in a Collection. So doing a delete on a Task would also lead to delete of all TaskSteps instances in your steps Collection, and also delete the Operator operator in TaskStep. Brave, but likely to fail since you have @ManyToMany relations involved - other TaskStep instances might reference the very Operator your delete is cascaded to. Normally only cascade save-update (or map relation at a Component/Embedded) and handle deletes manually. If you though are sure that your collection is the only one referencing another entity you could use ALL and also DELETE-ORPHAN and thus cause referenced Entities to be deleted simply by removing them from the Collection.

@IndexColumn is used if you want the order of the objects in the List to be remembered. If you don't care, skip it and your relation will have Bag semantics (unordered, duplicated allowed). Often you don't want to see duplicates in a Collection, so the Set Collection should then be used.

Kind of long answer, sorry. Should've simply provided the code perhaps.

Comment: I have tested,if I just using the mappedBy in the mapping,the position would not be set. So I have to define the "joinColumn" twice, have a look at this :http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4390.  BTW,from your kind answer,I am confused about the bidirectional relation and bidirectional refer. In my example, both of the task and taskstep hold a refer to the other,this is bidirectional reference,but what is relation in this suitation? bi or un?

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship between Task and TaskStep is mapped twice : once in Task, and once in TaskStep. The @JoinColumn in Task should disappear, and the @OneToMany should have a "mappedBy" attribute:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "task")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@IndexColumn(name = "position")
public List<TaskStep> getSteps() {
    return steps;
}
```

Comment: Yes,you are right,but if I just set the relationship once, the position column in the taskstep cann ot work well, so I set them twice.(the order of the tasksteps of one task is requried in my app. Can you tell me about the cascade? I can not delete the task.

Comment: I suspect the position management doesn't work well when you add a mappedBy because you forget to initialize the inverse relationship when you add a step to a task. It's your responsibility to make sure both sides are modified. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460573/hibernate-bidirectional-manytoone-updating-the-not-owning-side-not-working/5460743#5460743. A relationship should always be mapped once, not twice.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. in my task,when I add a taskstep,I will update the taskstep's refer to the task,just as:"   public void addSteps(TaskStep ts) {
      steps.add(ts);
      ts.setTask(this);
   }
"  so,I think I have initilize the relationship. BTW,is this the reason I can no delete the task object? since yesterday,when I do not add the "indexColum" in the taskStep, I also can not deleteit.