# Hibernate @ManyToOne Collection doen’t update on the fly

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm pretty new to hibernate and @ManyToOne doesn't work. I have two DAO classes:

**CompanyDAO**

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class CompanyDAO implements Serializable {

  @OneToMany(cascade = { DETACH, MERGE, PERSIST,REFRESH }, 
  fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
  mappedBy = " companyEmployeeReference ")
  protected Collection< EmployeeDAO> employeeData = new ArrayList<EmployeeDAO>();
```

**EmployeeDAO**

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class EmployeeDAO implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private CompanyDAO companyEmployeeReference;
```

when I then create some EmployeeDAO via

```
public EmployeeDAO create(EmployeeDAO o) {
        em.persist(o);
        return o;
    }
```

and afterwards try to get this DAO from the Company side via:

```
public CompanyDAO getCompany(int companyID) {
        CompanyDAO company = em.find(CompanyDAO.class, companyID);
        return company;
    }
```

it doen't work. The employeeData of the found company is always empty.

However, when I stop the server after the employee creation. And then restarted it before `getCompany` everything is fine. I already search the internet (incl. stackoverflow) for hours but couldn't find the answer. The only think I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460573/hibernate-bidirectional-manytoone-updating-the-not-owning-side-not-working), but this seems to be a very manual answer, isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few clarifications. Vaguely speaking `Dao` is the thing which saves your entity. Not entity itself. Similar applies for `@Transactional`. This shouldnt be on entity level but instead on Service or Dao layer.

According to your problem - if you do this within same "session" then add to your `getCompany` `em.refresh(company);` between `find` and `return` lines.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for my problem was a mix of:

```
em.refresh(company)

em.flush();
```