# Hibernate using of @ManyToMany and update both ways

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have 2 classes, a Room class and a Student class. A Room can have many Students, while a Student also can have many Rooms. Therefore i used @ManyToMany relationship

```
public class Room {
  @ManyToMany
  private Collection<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

---

```
public class Student {
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="studentList")
  private Collection<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
}
```

Since i want to use 1 mapping table that is Room_Student, i was able to add a collection of Students to a Room. When I tried to add collection to a Student, hibernate did not save it.
Here it is

```
Collection<Student> collectionOfStudents=new ArrayList<Student>();
Room room1=(Room) session.get(Room.class, 1);
Student student1=(Student) session.get(Student.class, 1);
Student student2=(Student) session.get(Student.class, 2);
collectionOfStudents.add(student1);
collectionOfStudents.add(student2);
room1.getStudentList().addAll(collectionOfStudents)
session.update(room1);
```

This worked and inserted to table Room_Student

When i did

```
Collection<Room> collectionOfRooms=new ArrayList<Room>();
Student student1=(Student) session.get(Student.class, 1);
Room room2=(Room) session.get(Room.class, 2);
Room room3=(Room) session.get(Room.class, 3);
collectionOfRooms.add(room2);
collectionOfRooms.add(room3);
student1.getRoomList().addAll(collectionOfRooms);
session.update(student1);
```

it **did not insert** into table Room_Student for room2 and room3. 
Thanks for all the replies

edited 1:
i added

```
public class Student {
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="studentList",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  private Collection<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
}
```

This

```
student1.getRoomList().addAll(collectionOfRooms);
session.update(student1);
```

did not update/insert the rooms into table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your mappings, the `Room` is the owning side and `Student` is the owned side. So you will always have to add students to a room in order to create relationships between rooms and students. Doing it the opposite way will not work, even if you use Cascading. You will always have to define a owning side in the relationship in ORM and always use that side itself to create the relationships. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping) shed further light on the topic. Also, you should go through the JPA/hibernate documentations if you need to dive deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Satadru, Hibernate does not persist the other way, therefore i have to remove the mapping (**mappedBy**) , and both

**Student_Room** table
and 
**Room_Student** table 
will be created. This shows Room owns Students and Students owns Rooms
instead of **Student_Room** only

Yet the OJB work well this feature.