# Hibernate Search is it possible or recommended to do keywork search on specific collection

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to do what seems like a simple search query but am unable to find out if there is a way and if so is it efficient.

I am currently using hibernate with hibernate search 4.3.0. What I am trying to do is to search a specific collection. For example I have an Inventory class that contains a List of InventoryItem. I would like to perform a keyword search where only the items in a specific inventory are searched. Is it possible to limit the search to a specific. Both the Inventory and InventoryItem class extends DatastoreObject which has a @Id Long id field as it's primary key.

#### Inventory Class

```
/**
 * Inventory is a container of inventory objects.
 * 
 * @author chinshaw
 */
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Inventory extends DatastoreObject {

    @Size(min = 5, max = 256, message = "inventory name must be between 5 and 256 characters")
    @Column(length = 256)
    @Field
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 512, message = "inventory description cannot exceed 512 characters")
    @Column(length = 512)
    @Field
    private String description;

    /**
     * List of all inventory items in this object.
     */
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
...
```

#### My InventoryItem Class

```
/**
 * 
 * @author chinshaw
 */
@Entity
@Indexed
public class InventoryItem extends DatastoreObject implements IHasImage {

    /**
     * String manufacturer's serial number.
     */
    private String sin;

    /**
     * This is the name of the item.
     */
    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String name;

    /**
     * This is the text description of the object.
     */
    @Size(max = 200, message = "description must be less than 200 characters")
    @Field
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_id")
    private Inventory inventory;
```

...

#### Example code of what I am currently trying

```
public List<InventoryItem> searchItems(Long inventoryId, String searchContext) {

    FullTextEntityManager session = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(getEntityManager());
    EntityTransaction tx = session.getTransaction();



    QueryBuilder qb = session.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(InventoryItem.class).get();

    // How do I limit the search to only contain the inventoryId.
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query searchQuery = qb.keyword().onFields("title", "description").matching(searchContext).createQuery();
    javax.persistence.Query query  = session.createFullTextQuery(searchQuery, InventoryItem.class);

    // execute search
    List<InventoryItem> items = query.getResultList();

    tx.commit();

    return items;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the bool() method on QueryBuilder.  For instance, to filter the returned `InventoryItem`s such that they must belong to the `Inventory` with ID `inventoryId`, you can use:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query searchQuery = qb.bool()
    .must(qb.keyword().onFields("title", "description").matching(searchContext).createQuery())
    .must(qb.keyword().onField("inventory.id").matching(inventoryId).createQuery())
    .createQuery();
```

This will create an AND condition between your search on the title/description of the `InventoryItem`s  and the ID of the `Inventory` you want matched.

Note, however, that you must annotate `InventoryItem.inventory` as `@IndexedEmbedded` for it to be included in `InventoryItem`'s index.

Comment: Excellent answer!! I had to some refactoring of my entity ownership's to get it to work. One last question though, do you know of a way that I could possibly get this to work with the owning side of the relationship being in the Inventory class. To get it to work I had to change to using the mappedBy so that the inventoryItem is the owning side of the relationship. I was hoping I could leave it as a @OneToMany without the mapped by. This is not a deal breaker but it seems more natural that the Inventory class would own the InventoryItem in the entity relationship. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Your new configuration sounds correct.  As far as I understand, you want the owning side to be InventoryItem, even though it may not make sense conceptually.  For a better explanation, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2749719/1260254.