# JPA Bidirectional Relationship

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to establish Bidirectional Relationship between User and Address,

User 1---------->*Address

But

Address 1 -------> 1 User

**On referring the internet I got these information**

- For one-to-one bidirectional relationships, the owning side
  corresponds to the side that contains the corresponding foreign key
- The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its
  owning side by use of the mappedBy element of the OneToOne,
  OneToMany, or ManyToMany annotation. The mappedBy element designates 
  the property or field in the entity that is the owner of the
  relationship.

**But If I proceed as per information  then**

I need to use Mapped By on User Entity where Set <Address> hold OnetoMany mapping
At the same time I need to use Mapped By on Address Entity where user holds OnetoOne mapping

**Note :** But @JoinColumn on Address entity for user works fine. If I use mappedBy on either User Entity or Address Entity I got the exception stating that

> "The attribute [addresses] in entity class [class com.entity.User] has
>   a mappedBy value of [User] which does not exist in its owning entity
>   class [class com.entity.Address]. If the owning entity class is a
>   @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should
>   reference the correct subclass."

I am confused on how to use mapped By for this type of Bi-directional relationship.

Update :

```
<pre>
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
    private Set<Address> adresses;
} 


@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Post your User and Address classes or at least relevant parts of it with annotations. It will be easier to see what's the problem.

Comment: I've posted an answer, have a look at my answer on this other question (scroll down on the question until after the accepted answer to see my post there as well) for some more info on what the owning side means, how to use it, pitfalls, etc -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping

Comment: @jhadesdev : The link provided by you describes the usage of the mappedBy using an example of ManyToOne and OneToMany. But in my case its ManyToOne and OneToMany

Comment: If a User has many Addresses, the inverse relationship by definition is a ManyToOne- Many Addresses reference a single User.  In the database, this would mean the Address table had a foreign key to the User table.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany for an example and explanation, but the answer given by jhadesdev seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@OneToMany` can only have as inverse `@ManyToOne`, and not `@OneToOne`. `@OneToOne` can only have as mappedBy another `@OneToOne`, check the javadoc for those methods.

The mapping bellow gives you the meaning you want: one user can have many addresses, but an address can only refer to only one user using the id in the foreign key specified in `@JoinColumn`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<Address> adresses;
} 


@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn("your_foreign_key_name")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: In Address Entity, User is OneToOne Not ManyToOne

Comment: i've posted some more detail, I think the mapping i proposed gives you the meaning you need