# Explain the JPA term "owner"

Tags: database, jpa

Given the following JPA model:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id    
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer")
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

    //...
}

@Entity
public class ShippingAddress {
    @Id    
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Customer customer;

    //...
}
```

This will create a foreign key to the `customer` table in the `shipping_address` table i.e. `shipping_address.customer_id`.

From a database point-of-view, one would say that customer is the parent table and shipping_address is the child table, because

- An address cannot exist without a customer
- If a customer is deleted, their address must also be deleted

However, according to JPA, the owner of this relationship is `ShippingAddress` because the JavaDoc for `mappedBy` states

> This element is only specified on the inverse (non-owning) side of the association.

I find it extremely confusing that the owner of the relationship according to JPA is what (from the database point-of-view) would be considered the child table. Is there a way to reconcile this apparent contradiction?

Comment: I agree with you that, in your example, `Customer` "owns" `Address`; but I think the JPA spec says `Address` "owns" the _relationship_. Sorta consistent with your argument, the relationship cannot exist without the `Address`. : )

Answer (score 0):

In short: as posted before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033580/specifying-the-owner-of-a-unidirectional-onetoone-jpa-mapping), the owning side of the relation is the one that holds the FK in the DB table.

You can read this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068644/1385048) for a full explanation why.