# What does "is this entity the owner of the relationship mean" in jhipster

Tags: spring, jhipster

I was just generating an entity in my microservice with jhipster when it asked me the following question: **is this entity the owner of the relationship mean?**
Unfortunately I could not find anything in the documentation of jhipster anyhting about it.

Comment: not really, maybe I did not get it... 
the example is not for many-to-many does that mean in many-to-many examples I have to put mappedBy to both sides? But what is the benefit of owning an relationship mean

Comment: Please check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping , it explains the meaning of the owning side. This definition is valid for many ORM implementations and it should be as such for Jhibster.