# Cannot field a value in Spring JpaRepository by list field ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to find a sensor by its ID and its user ID, which it belongs to.

**Repository:**

```java
@Query("SELECT * from sensors LEFT JOIN users_sensors us on sensors.sensor_id = us.sensor_id " +
        "WHERE sensors.sensor_id = :sensorId AND us.user_id = :userId")
Optional<Sensor> findBySensorIdAndUsersId(@Param("sensorId") Long sensorId, @Param("userId") String userId);
```

**Populated data before calling a method:**

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES('user1');

INSERT INTO sensors (fk_sensor_type) VALUES(0);

INSERT INTO users_sensors (user_id, sensor_id) VALUES('user1', 1);
```

**Sensor class contains:**

```java
@Id
@Column(name = "sensor_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long sensorId;

private int sensorType;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sensors")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

**User class:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_sensors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sensor_id")
    )
    final List<Sensor> sensors = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors
    // Getters and setters
}
```

**users_sensors scheme:**

```sql
create table users_sensors
(
    id        bigint primary key not null generated by default as identity,
    user_id   text               not null,
    sensor_id bigint             not null,
    foreign key (sensor_id) references sensors (sensor_id)
        match simple on update no action on delete no action,
    foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
        match simple on update no action on delete no action
);
```

**Method:**

```java
private static final Sensor sensor = new Sensor();

public void shouldReturnUserSensor() {
    String userId = "user1";

    // user is PRESENT
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);

    // inserts & returns 2
    sensor.setUsers(List.of(user.get()));
    sensor.setSensorType(0);

    Long newSensorId = sensorRepository.save(sensor).getSensorId();

    // expected sensor is NULL
    Optional<Sensor> expectedSensor = sensorRepository.findBySensorIdAndUsersId(newSensorId, userId);
}
```

My **expectedSensor** is NULL and not found. When I run exact query provided above in the post under `Repository` in Query Console, it returns correct values, but in the app it does not. How to solve this issue?

Comment: @Stultuske, to which `userId` are you referring as not instantiated?

Comment: When you call `save(sensor)` the sensor doesn't seem to be associated with the user, at least I can't see any code that makes that connection.

Comment: @CaptainJacky my mistake, I missed the String. I was expecting a numerical field. but that query is on the sensor repository, those fields aren't in the sensor table

Comment: @Thomas, I've added the sensor class and updated the method, please check.

Comment: @Stultuske, in my model class I use `@Column` to refer to correct table name. `sensorId` in model refers to `sensor_id` in table.

Comment: @CaptainJacky have you tried add  `nativeQuery = true` property to `@Query`?

Comment: Did you try using a JPA query instead of a native SQL query?

Comment: @artiomi run my query? what query?

Comment: @Stultuske i have updated the comment, I'm sorry for tagging

Comment: @artiomi, I've just tried with `nativeQuery = true` - same result.

Answer (score 0):

New relations in the database should be added on the owning side, according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068644/10231374):

> Using mappedBy, If we only call person.getDocuments().add(document),
> the foreign key in ID_DOCUMENTS will NOT be linked to the new
> document, because this is not the owning /tracked side of the
> relation!
>
> To link the document to the new person, you need to explicitly call
> document.setPerson(person), because that is the owning side of the
> relation.
>
> When using mappedBy, it is the responsibility of the developer to know
> what is the owning side, and update the correct side of the relation
> in order to trigger the persistence of the new relation in the
> database.

This means that a sensor should be added to a user on the user's side, or the sensor should be switched to be owning side.

You should also consider declaring [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) as shown below, which doesn't require writing JPQL or native SQL.

```
public Optional<Sensor> findByIdAndUsers_Id(Long sensorId, String userId);
```

Comment: My `expectedSensor` still is not present when returned via this method, but it gets populated in the database.

Comment: Can you please add User class and join table (users_sensors) scheme to the question?

Comment: The answer was also updated, check if it helps.

Comment: As I understood If I wanted to stay with my current structure, I have to add first get user sensors, add the sensor that I added to the repository, then save the user. I did all this, but now it retrieves the sensor with empty users list. For debugging I retrieved the user, and it prints correctly his sensors. But retrieving sensor by userId and sensorId shows empty users.

Comment: Check the content of users_sensors table on the database after adding sensors to user. It should contain all relations created.

Comment: `users_sensors` table does have newly created relation - `userId='user1', sensorId=2`